# Read Newer Theme Attributes On Older Platform

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to read attribute values from themes and styles which were designed for platforms that are newer than I am running my application on.

*Please don't ask why. If you know anything about the libraries I write then you should already know that I like to push the capabilities of the platform :)*

I am operating under the presumption that when Android styles are compiled the attribute constants are what is used for the keys and therefore should theoretically be able to be read on any platform somehow. This is what I have observed to be happening with layout XMLs in my other libraries with no trouble.

Here is a base test case which shows the problem. This should be compiled using Android 3.0+.

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.BreakMe">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.BreakMe</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.BreakMe" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The fact that this uses `android:actionBarStyle` specifically is irreleveant. All that should be understood is that its an attribute which was only available starting with Android 3.0.

Here are the way that I have tried to access these values thus far on platforms **prior to Android 3.0**.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Break Me"
    style="?android:attr/actionBarStyle"
    />
```

and

```
<declare-styleable name="Whatever">
    <item name="datStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>

<style name="Theme.BreakMe.Take2">
    <item name="datStyle">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Break Me"
    style="?attr/datStyle"
    />
```

and

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarStyle, outValue, true);
```

and

```
int[] Theme = new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize };
int Theme_actionBarSize = 0;
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Theme);
int ref = a.getResourceId(Theme_actionBarSize, 0);
```

and

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ActionBar, android.R.attr.actionBarStyle, 0);
```

All of them result in this error in LogCat:

```
E/ResourceType(5618): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102ce
```

The `0x010102ce` constant is the attribute value of `android.R.attr.actionBarStyle` which seems to indicate the platform is rejecting the attribute before I can even get a chance to access its value.

I am looking for any other way to read attributes like this from the Theme. I'm fairly sure that once I've obtained the style reference I won't have trouble reading its attributes.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am operating under the presumption that when Android styles are compiled the attribute constants are what is used for the keys and therefore should theoretically be able to be read on any platform somehow.

Possibly, though that is not how I am interpreting the C++ source code that raises the error you are seeing. Check out `ResTable::Theme::applyStyle()` in `frameworks/base/libs/utils/ResourceTypes.cpp`.

My interpretation is that Android has what amounts to an in-memory table of packages->types->possible entries:

```
numEntries = curPI->types[t].numEntries;
```

Your entry index is higher than the highest known entry:

```
if (e >= numEntries) {
    LOGE("Style contains key with bad entry: 0x%08x\n", attrRes);
    bag++;
    continue;
}
```

It is possible that they handle this different for `android` versus other packages -- `android` uses known values at firmware build time (and your generated entry index is higher, because it is from a newer platform), non-`android` ones assume anything's valid.

If my guesswork is correct, what you want to do will not work. That being said, my C++ days are *seriously* in my rear-view mirror, so I may be misinterpreting what I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this so thoroughly.

Comment: Little OT, How did you know/think to look for ResourceTypes.cpp? I see a lot of questions answered by you @CommonsWare so I'm inclined to think of you as an Android expert.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing the end goal here, but I put together the following example that was able to read out all the attributes without issue on any 2.x device.  The example was compiled against a 3.0 targetSdk.

**styles.xml** (Declare the styles and themes)

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.NewFeatures" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBar</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Widget.MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget">
      <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**attrs.xml** (Declare the attribute groups you wish to obtain at runtime)

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="ActionBarNewFeatures">
    <attr name="android:actionBarStyle" />
  </declare-styleable>
  <declare-styleable name="MyWidgetNewFeatures">
      <attr name="android:padding" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** (Apply the custom theme)

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NewFeatures" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**SomeActivity.java** (Go digging for attributes)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.ActionBarNewFeatures);
    //Get the style ID for the widget
    int resid = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ActionBarNewFeatures_android_actionBarStyle, -1);
    a.recycle();

    a = obtainStyledAttributes(resid, R.styleable.MyWidgetNewFeatures);
    int padding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MyWidgetNewFeatures_android_padding, -1);
    a.recycle();

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(String.format("Padding will be %d px", padding));
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

As long as I compile the example against 3.0 so it can resolved all the attribute names; on every 2.X device/emulator I have this will correctly read into the theme and then into the widget style to get the scaled padding dimension I had set.

Hope I didn't miss something big.

Comment: This looks very promising except I didn't observe the same results as you. The error still rears its head in logcat. https://github.com/JakeWharton/PreHCABAttrs

Comment: I just realized that all the devices I tested this on are 2.3 (thought one was 2.2, but it apparently got an update).  I see the same error on 2.1/2.2, so it looks like they lifted the restriction in 2.3.  Your example works on 2.3 (well, it crashes but that's because navigationMode doesn't return as an int if it's not defined...it returns as a reference id).  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, You must define a few themes. For old devices use folder res/values-v11/themes.xml. See section "Using Holo while supporting Android 2.x" in the http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question.