# ActionBarSherlock - Style contains key with bad entry

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm trying to use **ActionBarSherlock** in one specific activity which I've declared in the Manifest like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Bla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" />
```

My Activity code is this:

```
public class Bla extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bla);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list =
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.cartaz_filters, R.layout.actionbar_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.actionbar_spinner_dropdown_item);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, every time I run this in an Android 2.1 I get the following error:

```
E/ResourceType(9672): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01000000
```

I think this might be related with this question: [Read Newer Theme Attributes On Older Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814109/read-newer-theme-attributes-on-older-platform) but I don't know how to solve it.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What API are you targeting and what are your max/min API levels in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: android:maxSdkVersion="15"
android:minSdkVersion="7"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is because you are using theme attributes that were not present on the platform on which you are running your application. Despite the giant red error log that it adds, it's more of a warning as it does not affect the other attributes. The newer attributes are never read on the older platforms.

The linked question from me was my attempt to not have to require ABSv4 use mirrored attributes.

If you really want to get rid of the error you can create two sets of your styles. One in `values/` for the compatibility action bar and one in `values-v14/` that use the prefixed attributes for the native action bar.

And please, please, please, please **do not** use `maxSdkVersion`. Use `targetSdkVersion` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I use targetSdkVersion. maxSdkVersion was my last effort to correct the error.

Comment: I have lots of styles and I can't figure out which one is causing the problem. Is there a way to find it based on the resource hex code?

Comment: I have the same question as @gsingh2011. Does the hex code help locate the problem?

Comment: Logging      getResources().getResourceName(id)  for example getResources().getResourceName(0x7f0a00f7) will give you the name of the style resource in most cases.