# Logcat error on upgrading android-support-v7-appcompat: Style contains key with bad entry

Tags: java, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, android-resources, android-logcat

Using the SDK Manager, we updated all installed SDKs and installed the **Android 5.0.1 (API 21)** SDK platform. Then, in Eclipse we exchanged the current **android-support-v7-appcompat** library with the new one (Rev. 21).

The appcompat project would not compile, so we took this [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro). That is, we changed the Android version to Android 5.0 both for the actual project as well as the appcompat project.

Now it does compile. However, when running the app Logcat prints the error:

`E/ResourceType(4537): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479`

Moreover, it prints a couple of warnings, all similar to this one:

`I/dalvikvm(4537): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted`

Finally, it ends up with a NullPointerException referring to [Activity.findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

We used Androids [step-by-step instruction](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to import appcompat as a project with resources.
Our app's Manifest uses

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686818/actionbarsherlock-style-contains-key-with-bad-entry) seems to be related but it does not really provide a solution for our problem...