# Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-theme

I just created a new Android Studio project, and I tired running the default project on my Android phone. 
When I run the project, I got an error saying:
`Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479`
I tired to look  up this error, people are saying it has something to do with the theme.

The phone's Android version I'm using is a 4.0.4

For the layout xml page. I'm using API 14, Android 4.0
For the theme, I'm using Holo. The Holo theme didn't show up on my phone, but it did managed to display "hello world".

value/styles.xml:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

value-v21/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.louis.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All I changed from the default "Hello World" project is the (API 14, Android 4.0) and the (Holo theme). I also had the same error for my other Android projects. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Let me try to update my SDK, I hope that will help.

Solution: I updated my SDK, and the problem is solved!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore this error, unless something is not displaying in the way you like it.

Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691550/1310343